# moving a button using css in javascript

Tags: javascript, css, positioning

I am trying to move a button with the id 'button' when different radio buttons are clicked, my following code is not working correctly whereby the button is firstly in the wrong position when 'notadmin' is selected and when 'yesadmin' is selected the button dissapears without a trace from my page. Here is my code:

```
function showbroker() {
    var button = document.getElementById('button').style;
    if(document.getElementById('notadmin').checked == true) {
      document.getElementById('brokerarea').style.display = 'block';
     button.position = "absolute";
     button.left = "150px";
     button.top = "400px";
      }
    else if(document.getElementById('yesadmin').checked == true) {
     document.getElementById('brokerarea').style.display = 'none';
     button.position = "absolute";
     button.left = "150px";
     button.top = "290px";
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post your HTML?

Comment: @DavidePastore shoot, completely forgot to link the javascript at the end of my button, I am unsure what I would add though.
<input type="submit" name="submitter" id="button" value="insert/update">

Comment: Post the entire html.

Comment: Davide is referring to all the **relevant** html elements that would act as containers/parents for your input.. if you specify `position:relative` and `display:block` on the container/parent of the input, the absolute position of the child element (your input) will be relative to the upper left point of **that parent element**..

Answer (score 0):

I guess this is because of position absolute.and if this is not then I would be able to help you if you could post your HTML .

Answer (score 0):

You haven't provided enough HTML so I will have to provide a generic answer. I have posted some code that moves a button onclick. this **may** be helpful, but if not just post your code and I'll answer your question specifically

```js
function i(id){return document.getElementById(id);}
var left = 0;
var top = 0;
i("b").onclick = function(){
  top+=15;
  left+=30;
  i("b").style.left = left + "px";
  i("b").style.top = top + "px";
}
```

```css
#b{
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<input type="submit" name="submitter" id="b" value="click me!">
```

Comment: hmm.. this snippet is not correct.. not all browsers declare `body` to be `position:relative` by default..

Comment: @BrettCaswell the idea was to show how one can move an element with javascript

Comment: roger.. nevermind.. it may indeed work, it would appear that the snippet is being flagged for security reason. allow-access-origin flag isn't set; thus chrome is blocking the snippet from running..